# Our enemy is the virus - NOT EACH OTHER!

Tags: grammar

**Our enemy is the virus - NOT EACH OTHER!**

This sentence is quoted in

https://edition.cnn.com/2020/07/14/health/us-coronavirus-tuesday/index.html

Does this sound right? If so, does it mean that (from a grammatical point of view) one could say "Our enemy is each other"?

Comment: Of course, you're right. I meant from a grammatical point of view. I'll edit.

Comment: @marcellothearcane - I think the OP is asking whether "our enemy is each other" is grammatically valid in itself, not whether it means the same thing as the previously quoted phrase.

Comment: @AristideHerve are you asking if "Our enemy is each other" is the same as "Our enemy is the virus - NOT EACH OTHER!"?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. Please see my edit. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: The antithesis of "We have met the enemy and he is us," yet the same.

Comment: The revision you suggest means the **opposite**, not the same thing. And simply asking if either is grammatical is proofreading, which is off topic.